# You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When running a GAE app with:

```
$ mvn appengine:devserver
```

Somewhere down the line it shows this error:

```
You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server.
```

What is does it mean, and how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give a definitive answer because you don't provide much context, and because it's been a while I haven't used GAE, but here's my guess.

It means that on the real appengine, on Google's machines, you won't be able to access the files in the working directory (and you won't be able to write any file at all), because that is forbidden in this environment.

And I guess it shows this error because on your development server, you're executing some code that is accessing the current directory. So it warns you that the code, although working fine on your development server, won't work on the real app engine.

To get rid of the warning, find the code doing that, and modify it.

Read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Sandbox for more details.